# How to screen print two columns of values from Pandas?

Tags: python, formatting, special-characters

Say I have a distribution which I have loaded in a `pandas` DataFrame. My data frame consists of 5 columns A to E, and I want to screen print the average and standard deviation next to each other:

```
avg=df.mean()
stdev=df.std()

Avg                St Dev
A    87.1717       A   1.354
B    87.0517       B   0.789
C    84.1717       C   1.221
D    86.8000       D   3.214
E    84.1705       E   4.170
```

**How can I do this by playing with the `print` formats?** I might do the following

```
print '%-10s' '%s' % ('Avg','St Dev')
print '%-10s' '%s' % (df.mean(),df.std())
```

but then only the headers would be correctly displayed, and the values are in a mess:

```
Avg       St Dev
A    87.1717
B    87.0517
C    84.1717
D    86.8000
E    84.1705
dtype: float64A    1.354
B    0.789
C    1.221
D    3.214
E    4.170
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could combine the two separate columns in a new dataframe (use pd.DataFrame(means,stds)). It should be easy to print this new dataframe with the columns next to each other (even though not most efficient).

Not sure if relevant, but you could use the pandas describe functionality? You can find it here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be creating a new DataFrame with 2 columns(Avg & St Dev), and then just print the new DataFrame.